# Firebase database: Does the user download the whole database every time?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have such a firebase data and rule structure:

[image]

So...my firebase data downloads are very high..almost 1GB per day. (300 users, 3,5MB database size) I think the reason for this is that the user downloads the whole database to get to the **"users/$uid"** section. It only requires data from the **$uid** area. How is it possible not to download the other data about it?

**My database ref in code**

Like: `this.dataObjRef = this.afDatabase.object("data/users/${uid}");`

**What I tried**

I tried to set `".read" : "false"` directly in the **rules** above, but then none of the data is accessible, although **".write"** at the bottom of the says **"$uid": "$uid === auth.uid"**

Do you have any idea?

Comment: The line of code you showed will only download data for that precise path `/data/users/${uid}`. To learn what a single client reads, you can profile your database: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/profile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep your data in client instead of download data every time [Disk Persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities)

But it doesn't look high data use in their. Maybe your code have some unusual query?

Comment: You´re right! I checked all page files..but I forgot to check my root app.component file, there was an old query which downloads the whole database. Thank you :D